# How to use slice() in react.js when fetching with react UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slice

i am trying to figure out how i can use "const currentPosts". I am mapping trough all the fetched objects (pakketjes) and i am showing each of them. But i would like to only show the amount of objects that is stated in the const currentPosts. Here is the code

```
export default function HomePagina() {
  const paperStyle = { padding: '20px 20px', width: 600, margin: "20px auto", backgroundColor: "#F2D2BD", borderRadius: "35px" };
  const [pakketjes, setPakketjes] = React.useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(2);
  const [postsPerPage, setpostsPerPage] = React.useState(2)
  const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = pakketjes.slice(firstPostIndex, lastPostIndex)

  //useffect = voor bij pagina starten om info te loaden, in dit geval alle pakketjes tonen bij opstart
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/pakketje/getAll")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setPakketjes(result);
      }
      )
  }, []);


 return (
    <>
      <Appbar />
      <br />
      <Container>
        <div>
          <img src={AllePakketjes} width="410" height="350" alt="" style={{ marginLeft: "365px" }} />
        </div>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>Alle pakketjes</h1>
        <Paper elevation={3} style={paperStyle}>
          {pakketjes.map(pakketje => (
            <Paper elevation={6} style={{ margin: "10px", padding: "15px", textAlign: "left", backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "25px" }} key={pakketje.id}>
              <b>Pakketje&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</b>
              <br /><br />
              <b>ID:</b>{pakketje.id}
              <br /><br />
              <b>Status: </b>{pakketje.status}
              <br />
              <b>Code:</b>{pakketje.code}
              <br /><br />
              <Button variant="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: "#AE0000" }} color="secondary" onClick={(e) => deletePakketje(pakketje.id, e)}>
                Delete <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
              </Button>&emsp;&emsp;
              <Link to={`/pakketjeUpdaten/${pakketje.id}`}>
                <Button variant="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: "Navy" }} color="secondary">
                  Update <ReplayIcon fontSize="small" />
                </Button>
              </Link>&emsp;&emsp;
              <Button variant="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }} color="secondary" onClick={(e) => statusOnderweg(pakketje.id, e)}>
                Verzenden&emsp;<LocalShippingIcon fontSize="small" />
              </Button>
              <br />
              <br />
            </Paper>
          ))
          }  
        </Paper>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You never use `currentPosts` variable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could just replace the `pakketjes.map` with `currentPosts.map`.

This will iterate through the subset of `pakketjes` specified by `currentPosts` rather than the entire array.

Comment: I have tried to do it like three times but i have placed the currentPosts in curly braces {}. It works perfectly fine without the curly braces, thank you sir!